# What is meant by artistic qualities and Can anyone point out some of these qualities?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, descartes, art

What is meant by artistic qualities? Can anyone point out some of these qualities?

Comment: I think, this are some of artistic qualities: **expressiveness, virtuosity, curiosity, originality, good taste, interesting overlaps, emotionality, virtuosity, sensitivity, profoundness**

Comment: Question left open because of JustMe's expansive comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I see art as on a continuum with craft - the painters of the
> Rennaissance were considered craftsmen. But art, seems distinguished
> by being in dialogue of a creator with their peers or audience, that
> extends or in some way transforms what can be expressed there. It is
> 'high' craft.

Taken from this discussion: [Video games as new art](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70048/video-games-as-new-art/77615#77615)

I feel the true power of art is transformation, of the artists experiences, of audiences, of ideas about what art is and can do.

I would relate it to play, as similarly in the mode of exploration of new ways to create, which we engage in when the other layers of our hierarchy of needs have been met.

> "Man's maturity: to have regained the seriousness that he had as a
> child at play." - Nietzsche

I would look to a temperament that wants to be creative with what creativity itself is.